# fetch records from the column with the max date column

Tags: sql, oracle

For the below table

```
    ID           DATE              FIELD1           FIELD2       FIELD4
    123456  01.07.2014 00:00:00   EMPLOYER GROUPS     TMC       SELECT CARE HMO
    123789  01.07.2017 00:00:00   EMPLOYER GROUPS     MQC       SELECT CARE HMO
```

How to select only one row that have max(date)? i.e. 01.07.2017

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 12+, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
order by date desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In earlier versions, you an use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by date desc
    ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

If you need more than one record with the same maximum date:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t);
```

Comment: i need one one record with max(date). in this scenario, i can have multiple date records.

Comment: @nawaraj . . . The two original queries return one record.

Comment: @nawaraj: So there can be multiple records with the same date and you want to leave it up to chance which of the max date records you select?

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from theTable
where Date = (select max(date) from theTable)
```

Should do it. Add a `top 1` if multiple rows have the same date.

Answer (score 0):

For tsql / SQL Server you can use the below

```
DECLARE @max_date datetime;
SELECT @max_date = max(DATE) from table_name;
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table_name WHERE DATE = @max_date;
```

The 'TOP 1' makes sure you only receive 1 row.
Which row this is will arbitrary though, unless you add an 'ORDER BY' statement in your query.

Answer (score 0):

*Alternatively*

`dense_rank()` function may be used as :

```
select dt, ID
  from
(
select dense_rank() over (order by "Date" desc) as dr,
       "Date" as dt,
       ID
  from tab
)
where dr = 1;
```

or if you're sure about there's no *tie*(*for the column "Date"*), even `row_number()` function may be used :

```
select dt, ID
  from
(
select row_number() over (order by "Date" desc) as rn,
       "Date" as dt,
       ID
  from tab
)
where rn = 1;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f2ae/7)